# how to fetch records between two timestamps in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a column of TIMESTAMP(6) datatype in oracle and have values like 2022-04-01 18:02:42 and i wanna fetch all the records that falls between two datetime. I tried like below but no luck,

```
select * from table 
where column BETWEEN '2022-04-01 18:02:42' and '2022-11-03 19:28:57' -- no records
```

tried this too,

```
select * 
from table 
where column BETWEEN to_date('2022-04-01','yyyy-mm-dd') 
                 and to_date('2022-11-03','yyyy-mm-dd') -- a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

and,

```
select * 
from table 
where column BETWEEN to_timestamp('2022-04-01','yyyy-mm-dd') 
                 and to_timestamp('2022-11-03','yyyy-mm-dd') -- a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.
```

I want to fetch records falls in this dates!

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of "`column`"?

Comment: data type of column is TIMESTAMP(6)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly have to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT as follows:
`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';`
`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS';`

Then running the query using TIMESTAMP literal as follows:

`SELECT * FROM   table_name WHERE  column_name BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2022-04-01 18:02:42' AND     TIMESTAMP '2022-11-03 19:28:57';`

Comment: The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter should have no bearing as you are using a `TIMESTAMP` column in your table and a `TIMESTAMP` literal in the query and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is for the implicit conversion of strings to `DATE` data types (and vice versa) so it will never be used as (1) you are using `TIMESTAMP`s and not `DATE`s (and if the session parameter was required it would be the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter) and (2) you are not performing any implicit conversion to or from a string (since you use `TIMESTAMP`s throughout).

Comment: TIMESTAMP in front of the given time string doesn't work, given invalid syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the literal into DATE using TO_DATE and required format mask to compare the timestamp column with the input timestamp values.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A TIMESTAMP);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(to_date('2022-04-10T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(to_date('2022-05-01T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(to_date('2022-03-01T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

A
----------------------------
10-APR-22 03.39.00.000000 PM
01-MAY-22 03.39.00.000000 PM
01-MAR-22 03.39.00.000000 PM

SELECT *
     FROM t
  WHERE A BETWEEN
            to_date('2015-04-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
             AND
            to_date('2022-05-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-APR-22 03.39.00.000000 PM
01-MAY-22 03.39.00.000000 PM
```

Comment: but my record is already in TIMESTAMP format such as 2022-04-01 18:02:42, 2022-11-03 19:28:57

Comment: I gave you an end to end process. You would just need the SELECT statement. Obviously change the table name and column name to fit your casee

Comment: I got you, might be u didnt understand the question correctly, I have a column of datatype TIMESTAMP and in this column have data in the format of TIMESTAMP such as '2022-04-01 18:02:42', now i want to fetch records between these timestamp
but u give solution that u storing the dates of format '01-MAR-22 03.39.00.000000 PM'.

Comment: Dates and TIMESTAMPs are stored in an Oracle proprietary format. They are displayed based on your format setting. Try the query MTO and I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TIMESTAMP` literals:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2022-04-01 18:02:42'
                   AND     TIMESTAMP '2022-11-03 19:28:57';
```

or `DATE` and `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` literals:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name BETWEEN DATE '2022-04-01' + INTERVAL '18:02:42' HOUR TO SECOND
                   AND     DATE '2022-11-03' + INTERVAL '19:28:57' HOUR TO SECOND;
```

or `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-04-01 18:02:42', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                   AND     TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-11-03 19:28:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

or `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name BETWEEN TO_DATE('2022-04-01 18:02:42', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                   AND     TO_DATE('2022-11-03 19:28:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I tried all your suggestion didnt work anyone to me
showing 
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: Firstly have to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT as follows:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
select sysdate from dual;

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS';
select sysdate from dual;

Then running the query using TIMESTAMP literal.
Its worked for me
Thanks.

Comment: all above query gives you incorrect result, which include records before and after the given date.

Comment: @Rajesh All the above queries are correct and will not include records outside the given date range (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U15U8D_J)). If you are finding that there are issues with your data then **YOU** need to provide a [MRE] which demonstrates the problem to replicate your issue because stating that things are "incorrect" without anything to backup the statement is not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

I Was also facing this issue for quite a long, my query gave me results but also included extra records for Both prior and later dates as well, which was not right.

OLD Query (all commented query run but gives the wrong result):

```
select TO_0CHAR(time_stamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') time_stamp, count(*) as count from TABLE_NAME where
--time_stamp between TO_TIMESTAMP('22-AUG-2023 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_TIMESTAMP('22-AUG-2023 23:59:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
--time_stamp between TO_DATE('22-AUG-2023 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('22-AUG-2023 23:59:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
--time_stamp >= TO_DATE('22-AUG-2023 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and time_stamp <= TO_DATE('22-AUG-2023 23:59:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')    
group by time_stamp order by time_stamp asc;
```

It may work fine with different scenarios like between number range or only date etc. but with timestamp, it doesn't give correct result.

NEW Query (Correct Result !!!):

```
select TO_CHAR(time_stamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') time_stamp, count(*) as count from TABLE_NAME where
TO_CHAR(time_stamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') between '22-AUG-2023 00:00:00' and '22-AUG-2023 23:59:59'
group by time_stamp order by time_stamp asc;
```

In this query, we're converting the date into a string and then fetching the result between the given timestamp string.

Comment: **NEVER** rely on implicit string-to-timestamp conversions. Any user can change their `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` and then your query will either stop working or, worse, will give incorrect data. You should always use either `TIMESTAMP` literals or explicit conversions using `TO_TIMESTAMP` and an appropriate format model.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it's not giving the correct result. With TO_TIMESTAMP/TO_DATE format I always get some records beyond the given date range. So I switched to string way. 

Please try once at your end with a bunch of timestamp data from the above queries.